# Get an specific file from an specific folder

Tags: windows, file, windows-runtime, directory, winjs

Hi Im doing a Windows 8 Javascript App, y what to know how to get a file witch name is example2.dat from C:\Users\Me\Pictures\thifolder I tried using `Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromPathAsync("C:\Users\Me\Pictures\thisfolder");`
but it didnt work since i have another files like example1.dat, example3.dat example.jpg etc.

Hope i made my self clear, thanks in advance

Here is my code so far

```
    function here() {
        var getJsonStringAsync = function () {

            return   Windows.Storage.StorageFile.getFileFromPathAsync("C:\Users\Me\Pictures\thisfolder")   
//Also tried this
            //return Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.picturesLibrary.getFileAsync(u_u + "_" + u + "_" + ".dat")
                    .then(function (file) {
                        return Windows.Storage.FileIO.readTextAsync(file);
                    });
        };

        getJsonStringAsync().then(function (text) {
        document.getElementById("line").innerHTML = text;
    });
}
```

Comment: I would also like to get the text inside a folder, hope you can help

Answer (score 1):

The correct way to read a file in the pictures  library is this:
(don't forget to declare in the manifest of your app the access to the picturesLibrary)

```
var getJsonStringAsync = function () {
    var picturesLibrary = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.picturesLibrary;
    return picturesLibrary.getFolderAsync("thisfolder").then(function (folder){
        return folder.getFileAsync("example2.dat").then(function (file) {
            return Windows.Storage.FileIO.readTextAsync(file);
        });
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, here is how to play "song.mp3" which is in the music library:

Html:

```
  <audio id="player1">Your browser does not support audio </audio>
```

JavaScript:

```
        var ml = Windows.Storage.KnownFolders.musicLibrary;
            ml.getFileAsync("song.mp3").then(function (file) {
                // its a storage file, so create URL from it
                var s = window.URL.createObjectURL(file);
                player1.setAttribute("src", s);
                player1.play();
            //});
        });
```